# iPad - Displaying a drop down with a custom UIView?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create drop down menus for my app, and I want to be able to add custom UIView as the content of the menu.
ie: http://apcmag.com/images/ipod-apps-pages.jpg

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to create is called a popover.

Check this out http://blog.blackwhale.at/2010/04/show-a-custom-popover-view/

Comment: Currently the linked page is unable, please update the link in answer